# SMS are not blocking or deleting from android

Tags: java, android

I've write a code to delete SMS from inbox & block sms from a particular number. but its not working perfectly. 
Here is the manifest file where I set the priority 2147483647 (max int number)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dotnet.epomoload">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>



    <application
        android:enabled="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.dotnet.epomoload.BroadCastReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>




    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the code, in this condition broadCast function is not working. But the I'm getting the data. & I'm not getting the why the code is not working.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class BroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
public String blockingNumber = "BulkSMS";


private static final String LOG_TAG = "SMSApp";
/* package */
static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    String strFrom = "";
    String strMsg="";



    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null){
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++){
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }
            for (SmsMessage message : messages){
                strFrom = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                strMsg = message.getDisplayMessageBody();
            }
            if (strFrom.equals(blockingNumber)){
                this.abortBroadcast();
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Sms From Shohan"+strMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //removeMessage(context,blockingNumber);
                Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
                Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null,
                        null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                    int ThreadId = cursor.getInt(1);
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.
                                    parse("content://sms/conversations/"+ThreadId), "address=?",
                            new String[]{blockingNumber});
                    Log.d("Message Thread Deleted", blockingNumber);
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Since KitKat, your app cannot delete messages unless it's selected as the user's default messaging app, and `abortBroadcast()` no longer works at all for the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Android 4.4 the app cannot make write (mark as read, delete) operations on SMSs. To achieve this behavior, your app must be the default sms messaging app.

> However, if your app is designed to behave as the default SMS app,
>   then while your app is not selected as the default, it's important
>   that you understand the limitations placed upon your app and disable
>   features as appropriate. Although the system writes sent SMS messages
>   to the SMS Provider while your app is not the default SMS app, it does
>   not write sent MMS messages and your app is not able to write to the
>   SMS Provider for other operations, such as to mark messages as draft,
>   mark them as read, delete them, etc.
>   [Reference](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

When your app is set as the default app, your must check `Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage()`.